# Can I use a water tank and pump to feed a boiler?

Tags: water, boiler, pump, loft

As the title suggests I would like to know if I can use a water tank and pump to feed my boiler?

I want to get rid of my electric shower and currently I have large water tank with a pump feeding to the shower.

What I would like to do is remove the electric shower and then feed the water from the tank through the pump to the boiler;

1. thus improving pressure exiting the boiler?
2. If you are showering using the combi if someone flushes the loo or runs a hot or cold tap the person showering should not notice any changes in the temperature of the water?

Am I correct in my assumptions?